# How to create a map from the highest and lowest average values

Tags: qgis

Anybody can help me, how to generate the map from assumption data. 
I have 100 points data (from GPS reading) showing the **location of the bee nest**. Unfortunately there is no record on how much volume they harvested from each nest. However, from my respondent, they gave me the two values from the highest and lowest average of the volume production, ex. 5.99 liter (highest) and 1.03 liter (lowest).
I want to make a map to see where is the highest possible production volume per unit area and the other showing the lowest possible production volume per unit area.

Comment: There is no substitute for accurate values and anything you produce except for hive locations will be inaccurate at best. **don't put anything on paper unless you are certain of the values** they can come back to bite you and might, in the worst case, lead to your forced resignation. I would plot the hives and note the min and max collection values but *nothing more*. As soon as you put a mark on paper it's assumed to be accurate and someone may eventually be adversely affected by your map.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is create Voronoi diagramms around your points, calculate the area of the polygons and colour them graduated by the area.

But, as stated in the comments, make it clear that it is a **probability** diagramme.

Other things like the actual plants inside the polygons might affect the real distribution.

Comment: Than you Andre. :)

Comment: Yes, and put that in bold near the legend. There are more factors affecting the creation of honey than mere geographic area: colony size (more bees more honey - created and devoured), foliage cover, percent of foliage that creates flowers and even species - some flowers generate more nectar than others. @Andre this will give an answer but it could not be relied on.